# Text doesn't appear on GUI while using RMI

Tags: java, rmi

My aim is to make a simple chat program. I'm new at RMI. What I've got so far is that the server works. I start it. Then I start the client, it transfers the strings to the server through RMI. But then it doesn't appear on the GUI I made. That's where my problem lies.

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRsr4.png)

My StartClient class. I created a chatClient, and put the chatServer stub as parameter.

```
public StartClient() throws RemoteException, NotBoundException, MalformedURLException {
    chatServer = (ChatServer) Naming.lookup("rmi://localhost:1099/chatServer");
}

private void run() throws RemoteException, MalformedURLException, NotBoundException {
    ChatClientImpl chatClient1 = new ChatClientImpl(chatServer, "ikke");
    new ChatFrame(chatClient1);

    ChatClientImpl chatClient2 = new ChatClientImpl(chatServer, "bla");
    new ChatFrame(chatClient2);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws RemoteException, NotBoundException, MalformedURLException {
    StartClient start = new StartClient();
    start.run();
}
```

In the ChatClientImpl constructor I use the remote method register.

```
public ChatClientImpl(ChatServer chatServer, String name) throws MalformedURLException, NotBoundException, RemoteException {
    this.chatServer = chatServer;
    this.name = name;
    chatServer.register(this);
}
```

Now we're in the ChatServerImpl class, in the REGISTER method. I add the client to an ArrayList of clients. Then I use the method SENT to display the text. It calls the RECEIVE method that each client object has.

```
public class ChatServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ChatServer {
private List<ChatClient> clients;

public ChatServerImpl() throws RemoteException {
    this.clients = new ArrayList<ChatClient>();
}

public void register(ChatClientImpl client) throws RemoteException {
    clients.add(client);
    send("server", client.getName() + " has entered the room");
}

public void unregister(ChatClientImpl client) throws RemoteException {
    clients.remove(client);
    send("server", client.getName() + " has left the room");
}

public void send(String name, String message) throws RemoteException {
    for(ChatClient client : clients) {
        client.receive(name + ": " + message);
    }
}
}
```

This is where things go wrong. The textReceiver is ALWAYS null. (textReceiver is attribute/field of the client object.)

```
public void receive(String message) {
    if (textReceiver == null) return;
    textReceiver.receive(message);
}
```

The ArrayList of clients are server-side and all the clients in there all have their textReceivers set on null. If you look back at StartClient there's an important line. The new ChatFrame(chatClient). In the ChatFrame's constructor is where I set the textReceiver.

```
public ChatFrame(ChatClientImpl chatClient) {
    this.chatClient = chatClient;
    chatClient.setTextReceiver(this);
    String name = chatClient.getName();
    setTitle("Chat: " + name);
    createComponents(name);
    layoutComponents();
    addListeners();
    setSize(300, 300);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

This project works when I don't use RMI and they're in one package but once I separate them into client-server this problem arose. How do I communicate between them? Server-side I have an (irrelevant?) list of ChatClients that don't influence anything even though the text arrives.

Do I use RMI for every separate ChatClient and make the ChatServer connect with it and send the text like that? Seems very complicated to me. How do I go about this?

**EDIT:**

ChatClientImpl class

```
public class ChatClientImpl implements ChatClient, Serializable {
private ChatServer chatServer;
private TextReceiver textReceiver;
private String name;

public ChatClientImpl(ChatServer chatServer, String name) throws MalformedURLException, NotBoundException, RemoteException {
    this.chatServer = chatServer;
    this.name = name;
    chatServer.register(this);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void send(String message) throws RemoteException {
    chatServer.send(name, message);
}

public void receive(String message) {
    if (textReceiver == null) return;
    textReceiver.receive(message);
}

public void setTextReceiver(TextReceiver textReceiver) {
    this.textReceiver = textReceiver;
}

public void unregister() throws RemoteException {
    chatServer.unregister(this);
}
}
```

Comment: Is `ChatClientImpl` an exported remote object? Where does that happen? What does `setTextReceiver()` look like?

Comment: setTextReceiver() is a standard setter. I have edited the ChatClientImpl class in my original post. With "exported remote object" do you mean whether the class has extended UnicastRemoteObject? No. I've tried to do that but it gives me an IllegalArgumentException for chatServer.register(this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ChatClientImpl` class isn't an exported remote object, so it will be serialized to the server, and execute there. And because `register()` happens during construction, it will be serialized before the `setReceiverTextReceiver()` method is called. So, the corresponding field will be null. At the server. This is not what you want and it is also not where you want it.

So, *make* it extend `UnicastRemoteObject` and implement your `ChatClient` (presumed) remote interface. If you have problems with doing that, solve them. Don't just mess around with things arbitrarily. And it should *not* implement `Serializable`.

NB The signature of `register()` should be `register(ChatClient client)`. Nothing to do with the `ChatClientImpl` class. Ditto for `unregister()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I changed the signatures (& made `ChatClientImpl` extend `UnicastRemoteObject`). And it works. If I understand correctly it's because `ChatClientImpl` was a regular object at the server but once I extended it with URO it became an exported remote object and the server could remotely contact the client-side with its frames. (Got that right?) Also why did I get that earlier `IllegalArgumentException`? RMI only works with remote interface parameter instead of an exported remote object parameter? Again, thank you!

Comment: Correct. The `IllegalArgumentException` was something to do with the incorrect signature, or a disagreement between the object code versions. An exported remote object is never transported anywhere, only its stub, and its stub implements the remote interface rather than being an instance of the remote object of course, that being what the remote interface is for.